# SublimeLinter clang - Can't find basic headers

Tags: c++, sublimetext3, sublimelinter

I've recently installed Sublime Text 3 and I'm trying to get the SublimeLinter to work for C++. I've installed the "SublimeLinter-contrib-clang" linter with the Package Control, and the linter does activate. However, my issue is that the linter gives an error for every basic header, ie `#include <iostream>` in a basic Hello World program.

What I've tried to do:

- Installed clang, g++, and latest libstdc libraries
- Compiled and ran the program using clang from the terminal with `clang++ -v <name_of_file>`
- Tried and failed to manually include c++ library directory in the settings

The last one seems to be the best choice, but it seems I don't understand how Sublime settings work at all. Here is my User settings file: (color scheme and ignored packages lines were already there)

```
{
    "color_scheme": "Packages/User/SublimeLinter/Monokai (SL).tmTheme",
    "ignored_packages":
    [
        "Vintage"
    ],
    "SublimeLinter-contrib-clang": {
        "include_dirs": "/usr/include/c++"
    }
}
```

I've tried various formats (under "linters"->"clang", "clang", etc), but none of it works. Additionally, I'm not even sure this method will work.

Thanks~

(Using Ubuntu 14.04)

**Edit:**
My current user settings file:

```
{
    "color_scheme": "Packages/User/SublimeLinter/Monokai (SL).tmTheme",
    "font_size": 11,
    "ignored_packages":
    [
        "Vintage"
    ],
    "linters": {
        "clang": {
                "extra_flags": [],
                "include_dirs": [
                    "/usr/include/c++/4.8.2"
                ]
            }
    }
}
```

Comment: The headers are in several locations. Find them and add them to the list. In case you don't recognize it, the settings file is JSON.

Comment: @chris Thanks for the response, but I'm quite a bit confused. As for the JSON part, I was looking for the proper layout and location. I edited my post with my current Preferences.sublime-settings file, but it doesn't seem to have changed anything. As for the location, I checked and it includes iostream (which the linter is still giving an error for).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This was happening because the plugin used clang with the `-cc1` flag, which could be described as turning it into *internal* mode which omits options (i.e. platform specific location settings).

outlined in the [llvm docs](http://clang.llvm.org/docs/FAQ.html#i-run-clang-cc1-and-get-weird-errors-about-missing-headers)

The problem has since [been fixed](https://github.com/nirm03/SublimeLinter-clang/pull/14).

Answer (score 1):

IMHO it is better to not point out compiler include dir cause Xcode and clang may hidden it at all somewhere in /Application/Xcode/ folder.

I found useful following

```
"SublimeLinter": {
    "linters": {
        "clang": {
            "extra_flags": " -x c++ "
        }
    }
},
```